# Опубликованное в локальной сети веб-приложение видно только на том компьютере, где оно размещено

Tags: веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, iis

Разрабатываю веб-приложение. В какой-то момент решил его протестировать и опубликовал в локальной сети (на работе). Привязал к конкретному IP основного компьютера. Открыл с другого - всё в порядке. Далее дорабатывал приложение и тестировал только на основном компьютере, публиковал (Правой кнопкой по проекту -> Publish и т.д., как и ранее), открывал через указанный изначально IP/Название_проекта. Решил опять открыть с другого компьютера в локальной сети - не открывается. В настройках IIS вроде бы ничего не менял, в профиле для опубликования тоже.
Мог ли администратор сети изменить какие-то настройки, которые повлияли на работу IIS? Где искать неисправность?

Comment: Администратор мог изменить, спросите у администратора не закрывал ли он 80 порт, допустим.

Comment: @Bulson Уточнил - настройки сети никак не менялись. Попробовал опубликовать на другом компьютере (точнее администратор сети опубликовал на тестовом сервере). Та же проблема - на основном видно, на остальных нет. Может ли быть проблема из-за каких то файлов/настроек проекта?

Comment: А какой IP адрес слушает IIS ?